# How to get a discrete direction from quaternion rotations

Tags: rotations, quaternions, neural-networks

Say you have multiple quaternions (of the form q = w, x, y, z) that represent absolute rotations. How can you get a discrete direction from there such that if we see quaternion 0 for example we can deduce if the associated direction is :up, diagonal left or some kind of classification.
Ideally, it would be nice to avoid the use of euler angles if that's even possible.

The goal here being to classify the quaternions absolute rotations and use them as labels in a classification task for a neural net.

Comment: A possibility that occurs to me is to *quantize* the rotations. Something like the following: predefine a set of quaternions (or rotations if you like, there is the well known 2-to-1 correspondence). Then we need  a quantization algorithm that, given a a quaternion as an input, finds the closest match within the predefined set.

The catches are 1) to find a useful predefined set (one that works for you), 2) to develop a quick algorithm for finding the best match. For some "predefined sets" the latter task may be easier than for some others. 

Is this at all what you had in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I really appreciate your answer. I was thinking I could just use an unsupervised algorithm to do that so I guess that's also what you're thinking about in a way?